# Do the roots of this function all reside on the line $\Re(s) = \frac12$?

Tags: integration, number-theory, roots, hypergeometric-function

In [this video](https://youtu.be/wEtl7kNoD20), the following nice integral expression is derived:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(x^2+1)} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2\,\mathrm{e}}$$

Wondered about the more general form:

$$f(s) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{(x^2+1)^s} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

and managed to derive:

$$g(s) = f(s)\,\Gamma(s)\,2^s = {}_2F_0 \left([s, 1-s],[], -\frac12\right)\cdot \frac{\pi}{\mathrm{e}} \qquad s \in \mathbb{C}$$

which has the functional equation:

$$g(s) = g(1-s)$$

All roots of $g(s)$ seem to be complex and to reside on the critical line with $\Re(s) = \frac12$, e.g.:

```
0.5000000000 + 2.962548535*I
0.5000000000 + 4.534490718*I
0.5000000000 + 5.879867200*I
0.5000000000 + 7.107583837*I
0.5000000000 + 8.258936409*I
0.5000000000 + 9.355093826*I
...
```

Since these roots look quite regularly spaced, could the conjecture that they all reside on the critical be in reach of a proof?

Comment: I can't seem to evaluate $$\, _2F_0\left(s,1-s;;-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ but I get the result $$g(s)=2^s\, \Gamma(s) \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^s} \, dx=\sqrt{2 \pi}\, K_{s-\frac{1}{2}}(1)$$ in terms of the [Bessel K function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html). Its difficult to determine where all of the zeros lie as the magnitude of this function seems to quickly go to zero as $\Im(s)$ increases.

Comment: @StevenClark. I am typing the same ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Too long for comments.*

$$\Re(s)>0\qquad\implies \qquad g(s)=\sqrt{2 \pi } \,\,K_{\frac{1}{2}-s}(1)$$ which is easier to analyse than the hypergeometric function.

$$g\left(\frac{1}{2}+i y\right)=\sqrt{2 \pi } \,\, K_{-i y}(1)$$ is a real function.

An estimate of the $n^{\text{th}}$ root is given by
$$y_n \sim  \frac{31 }{13}n^{8/11}+\frac{18}{31}$$ Trying for the tenth root, Newton iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & y_{(k)} \\
 0 & 13.306620250 \\
 1 & 13.378420422 \\
 2 & 13.385796461 \\
 3 & 13.385882874 \\
 4 & 13.385882886 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

In comments, @Gary mentioned [this very recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.09306.pdf) which exactly adresses this problem. It also improves (equation $2.17$) the asymptotics given [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.01732.pdf)
$${\large y_n=\frac 12 e^{1+W \left(\frac{  (4 n-1)\pi}{2 e}\right)}}\left(1+O\left(\frac{\log (n)}{n^2}\right)\right)$$ which is already extremely good even for small values of $n$ (for example $y_1=2.98934$ instead of $ 2.96255$; $y_{10}=13.3896$ instead of $13.3859$).

Comment: What do you get by using the results of this paper? https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.09306

Comment: @Gary. This is a great paper.! Moreover, Lambert is there. Thanks

Comment: @Gary. I made my simplistic approximation 61 years ago for the NP I was working with.